# bad request from WCF web invoke

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, webinvoke

All my GET endpoints work like a champ, but I'm trying to implement a webinvoke method="POST".

I think there is something wrong with my format, but I can't tell what it is, could someone help?

```
[ServiceContract]
interface iFlowRate
{
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate = "Add?apikey={apikey}",RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
     string AddFlowRate(string apikey,FlowRate flowrate);
}
```

when I debug this it doesnt even get into this method. 
I'm calling the service like this.

```
string postData = "<FlowRate ><wellname>wellname</wellname></FlowRate>";
//Setup the http request.
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.KeepAlive = true;

StreamWriter streamwriter = new
StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
streamwriter.Write(postData);
streamwriter.Close();

// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
// Read the response
StreamReader responsereader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string strResponseData = responsereader.ReadToEnd();
```

Any ideas? BTW, using WCF 4.0, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the URL to which you're attempting the POST?

Comment: Also, how is the FlowRate class defined?

Comment: url = localhost:4369/FlowRate/Add?apikey=32q13e4-c78a-ce9d-e011-15eacd8e8958"; { [DataContract] public class FlowRate { [DataMember] public string wellname { get; set; } } }

Answer (score 1):

This was totally killing me until moments ago where I finally stumbled upon the answer.

Here is the source for my findings: [Wrapped BodyStyle in WCF Rest](http://dotnetfriendly.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/bare-and-wrapped-message-in-wcf-rest.html)

But I'll cut to the good stuff.

First, set the Namespace of your ServiceContract.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://mytagservice")]
```

Now, I'm sure there is another way to get this to work but this is how I hacked it. Set the BodyStyle to Wrapped. The default request format is XML so you don't need to set it here if you don't want to.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate = "Add?apikey={apikey}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Then change your xml to include the wrapper and namespace. Be extra careful of the tag names as they are case sensitive.

```
string postData = "<AddFlowRate xmlns='http://mytagservice'><flowrate><wellname>wellname</wellname></flowrate></AddFlowRate>";
```

Because it's using the wrapped message type this solution will work for as many parameters as you can want.